# linq where clause and count result in null exception

Tags: c#, linq

The code below works unless p.School.SchoolName turns out to be null, in which case it results in a NullReferenceException.

```
if (ExistingUsers.Where(p => p.StudentID == item.StaffID &&
                        p.School.SchoolName == item.SchoolID).Count() > 0)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

ExistingUsers is a list of users:

```
public List<User> ExistingUsers;
```

Here is the relevant portion of the stacktrace:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

How should I handle this where clause?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's SchoolName that is null and not p.School?

Comment: As a general note, instead of doing IEnumerable.Count(predicate) > 0, use IEnumerable.Any(predicate).  This will terminate execution for the first match that is found, potentially yielding a big speed up.

Comment: @Anthony: thanks very much, I think you're right about it being p.School that is null.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suspect `p.School` is null, not `SchoolName`. Simply add a null check before accessing `SchoolName`. Also, use `Any()` to check if there are any results instead of `Count() > 0` unless you're really in need of the count. This performs better since not all items are iterated if any exist.

```
var result = ExistingUsers.Where(p => p.StudentID == item.StaffID
                            && p.School != null
                            && p.School.SchoolName == item.SchoolID)
                         .Any();

if (result) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

For all database nullable columns, we should either add null check or do simple comparision `a == b` instead of `a.ToLower() == b.ToLower()` or similar string operations.
My observation as below:
As they get iterated through Enumerable of LINQ Query for comparision against with input string/value, any null value (of database column) and operations on it would raise exception, but Enumerable becomes NULL, though query is not null.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you want to get the null value (all the student, with school or not) Use left join.

There are a good example on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly (not at my developer PC at the moment and can't check with Reflector), using the `==` operator results in calling the [*instance* implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) `string.Equals(string)`, not the static implementation `String.Equals(string, string)`.

Assuming that your problem is due to `SchoolName` being null, as you suggest, try this:

```
if (ExistingUsers.Where(
    p => p.StudentID == item.StaffID 
    && String.Equals( p.School.SchoolName, item.SchoolID)).Count() > 0)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Of course, comments by other answers count as well:

- Using `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0` will generally perform better
- If `p.School` is the null, you'll need an extra check

Hope this helps.