# linq where clause causes exception

Tags: c#, linq

```
var nextItem = ql.Fragments.Where(x => x.AddedToFinal.Equals(false));
```

x.AddedToFinal is bool and ql.Fragments is not null
this linq statement  sporadically get this exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator1.MoveNext() at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)

There is a question already that should have answered this( [linq where clause and count result in null exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497522/linq-where-clause-and-count-result-in-null-exception))  but this is impossible since the field is a not null Boolean, and this isn't a database object it is a list

Just added: 
The code where I populate the list is multi-threaded. different fragments add items to the list after they have retrieved the items from the db:

.....

```
          xe = XElement.Parse(result);
          XmlFragment xf = new XmlFragment();
          xf.Fragment = xe;
          xf.LetterQueueOID = lq.LetterQueueOID;
          xf.ParentGroupNodeName = ParentGroupNodeName;
          xf.LinkingField = GroupNode.LinkingField;
          xf.GroupNodeName = GroupNode.GroupNodeName;

          lock (queuedLetters[lqOID])
          {
            if (lq.Fragments == null)
                lq.Fragments = new List<XmlFragment>();
            lq.Fragments.Add(xf);
          }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ql.Fragments` itself isn't null, but one of the elements in the enumeration is null. I'm guessing that is a problem in and of itself, but you could modify the statement to be:

```
var nextItem = ql.Fragments.Where(x => x != null && 
                                       x.AddedToFinal.Equals(false));
```

Although that doesn't solve the problem of why one of the elements in the collection was null to begin with.

Comment: Yes, somewhere the code is putting a null element into `ql.Fragments`, which is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I added a lock statement where the code adds values to the list. because it is a multi thread process to get all the fragments. is it possible my lock doesn't work properly? see my edits above

Comment: @greektreat - It's hard to say without seeing the code. I'm not exactly sure what code is running where without more details. Issues with multi-threading are always a possibility...but it could also be a problem inside the code building each fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> `x.AddedToFinal` is `bool` and `ql.Fragments` is not `null` this linq statement sporadically get this exception:

Then one of the elements of `ql.Fragments` is `null` so that

```
x.AddedToFinal
```

is throwing a `NullReferenceException` for some value of `x` in `ql.Fragments`. You could say

```
var nextItem = ql.Fragments
                 .Where(x => x != null)
                 .Where(x => !x.AddedToFinal);
```

but you should probably find out why there are `null` elements in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if x is null

```
var nextItem = ql.Fragments.Where(x => x != null && x.AddedToFinal.Equals(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all rows have a value for `AddedToFinal` ?!!

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator1.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
```

As you can see in exception Iterator can't move or read next row.
Be sure all rows have a value for this field.

Comment: AddedToFinal  is a bool not a bool? (i.e nullable)